# Which button has raised onclick even?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have created 3 `LinkButton` they all have same `onclick` event, now I have to find which button has called onclick event and it’s `ID`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="lnk_Click"/> 
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" onclick="lnk_Click"/> 
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" onclick="lnk_Click"/>
```

Comment: cast the button handler in click event into a link button then check its id to find wbich one is caller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're function should have a "sender" `object`.

```
void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;

    if (btn != null)
    {
        String id = btn.ID;
        //etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the sender object of course:

LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;

btn.ID

```
protected void MyBtnHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
          switch (btn.CommandName)
          {
                case "ThisBtnClick":
                    DoWhatever(btn.CommandArgument.ToString());
                    break;
                case "ThatBtnClick":
                    DoSomethingElse(btn.CommandArgument.ToString());
                    break;
           }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to use `CommandName` instead of just `Id` or compare the objects outright?

Comment: I was just cliping some code I had already typed.  no reason really.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the sender to `LinkButton`, from there you can get the id of the button that was clicked.

```
LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
string ID = lb.ID; //the id of the button that was clicked
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;
```

and then access it's properties. However, if your logic differs enough it may be good practice to seperate out into more than one handler.