# Getting Two Buttons to Execute the Same Funcion - How to Determine Which One?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-runtime

I've searched on MSDN and here, but doen't seem to have an answer.  Assume I have XAML code:

```
<button Name="button1" Click="ButtonHandler">
    some other stuff
</button>

<button Name="button2" Click="ButtonHandler">
    some other stuff
</button>
```

And in the CS code you have a simple handler:

```
private void ButtonHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to give each button, that are dynamically created by frame data, to have one handler and be able to uniquely identify themselves (name maybe?).  And then use the Handler to be able to sort out the Unique identifier to perform an action for the Click event.

I'm not finding much, but that could mean I am missing the obvious....

Comment: That's what [`Commands`](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) are for, I don't know if WinRT supports them, though

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

The `sender` parameter to your `ButtonHandler` method would be the button that was clicked. From that you could get the name, or some other identifier. Is this not enough for your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
private void ButtonHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (sender == button1)
   {
      //do stuff for btn 1
   }
   else
   {
      //do stuff for btn 2
   }
}
```

//Edit:
And go from here

Comment: Unless there is a better way, should have waited another ten minutes to post.

Roughly, cast the sender as a button and use the name to differentiate.  You can bind the name dynamically in xaml based on the allocated buttons at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the object sender to a button and get all the properties of it.

Here is another question asking this:

[Which button has raised onclick even?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916224/which-button-has-raised-onclick-even)